# WiFi web authentication using Wispr in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, wifi, wispr

I'm developing an app(android/iOS) which establishes connection with particular WiFi, but I'm getting popup(captive portal) which says WiFi requires web login to access internet.

WiFi provider is using WISPr for authentication.

Is there any way by which WiFi web authentication can be achieved from the app?

Comment: Do you mean that not getting popup to authenticate just in app's UI?

Comment: I do get a popup, I just want to make directly login in the provider's WiFi bypassing web login procedure

Comment: Okey, this should need API from provider's WiFi,just using mobile native method 
can not realize.